# Solution of some Bessel integrals

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, special-functions, improper-integrals

The solution of the integration
$\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x}J_v(\beta x)x^{\mu-1}dx$  is given in a standard form. Can I use the same result when the upper limit of the integration is finite?

The standard form of solution is: $(\alpha^2+\beta^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}\mu}\Gamma(\nu+\mu)P_{\mu-1}^{-\nu}[\alpha(\alpha^2+\beta^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}]$
where
$\alpha>0,\beta>0,Re(\nu+\mu)>0$

Comment: What standard form? (And probably no,regardless of what it is)

Comment: Hint: http://www.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_483.htm